# ip address taken as variable in bash

Tags: bash, variables, ubuntu, routes, ip

Why if I give those command lines:

```
  ip rule add from 10.222.192.0/25 table pdl
  ip route add 10.104.44.0/24 via 10.222.193.17 table pdl
```

everything works,
while if I execute this script:

```
#!/bin/sh

IPRULEADD=$(/sbin/ip rule add)
IPROUTEADD=$(/sbin/ip route add)

#
#

#----------- pdl ---------------------------
echo 100 pdl >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables

$IPRULEADD from 10.222.192.0/25 table pdl
$IPROUTEADD 10.104.44.0/24 via 10.222.193.17 table pdl
```

I get this error:

`from: can't read /var/mail/10.222.192.0/25`

?

Thanks

Comment: try adding `echo "$IPRULEADD"` etc after you have set those variables. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(...)` doesn't store code to be executed later; it produces the *result* of the enclosed code.

You want shell functions.

```
ip_rule_add () {
    /sbin/ip rule add "$@"
}

ip_route_add () {
    /sbin/ip route add "$@"
}

ip_rule_add from 10.222.192.0/25 table pdl
ip_route_add 10.104.44.0/24 via 10.222.193.17 table pdl
```

Whatever arguments you pass to the functions are correctly added to the argument list of `/sbin/ip` with the `"$@"` notation.

Comment: Thank you!
The first answer was the easiest and I was what I intended to do.
Yours was the most technical and interesting.
Can you explain me why I should not use the form IPRULEADD="/sbin/ip rule add"?

Comment: When you expand `IPRULEADD`, the value is subject to first word-splitting, then pathname expansion. In your current case, there doesn't make a difference. But consider something like `FOO="echo '9        3' *'`. If you expand `$FOO`, you first apply word-splitting to get 4 distinct words (`echo`, `'9`, `3'`, and `*`), so `echo` already has one more argument than you expected. Next, pathname expansion would expand `*` to the list of all files in the current directory. (If there are no files, the `*` is either treated literally or disappears, depending on the shell options in effect.)

Comment: I'm a bit new to bash, so it is not totally clear, but thank you

Answer (score 0):

Don't use subshells for storing strings in variables.

```
IPRULEADD="/sbin/ip rule add"
IPROUTEADD="/sbin/ip route add"
```

Comment: Parameters are the wrong abstraction for storing code. In general, word-splitting and pathname expansion will produce something other than the intended command-and-arguments.